# ASP.NET c# increase date value by number days on each button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I looked on here but I have not been able to find what I want to do.

I simply have a onclick event for a button,  and I want to increase the date value of a label by any number of days each time I click the button.
So lets say that number would be 2 days. If the current value of the label is  5/1/2016 when I click the button it should be 5/3/2016, and if again 5/5/2016 and so on. I can get it to do update  once on the first click  but not on a second click.  Here i my code

```
protected void NDateOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
      lblCurrentDate.Text = DateTime.Today.AddDays (2).ToString ("dd");
    }
```

I know it has somthing to to with the "Today" but I am not sure what to do from here
I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: "I know it has something to to with the "Today" " - well, yeah - you're adding the number of days to "today" _each time_.  Store the result somewhere so you have something to keep adding days to.

Comment: lblCurrentDate.Text = convert.ToDatetime(lblCurrentDate.Text)+DateTime.Today.AddDays (2).ToString ("dd"); ..something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need maintain the data in viewstate,  each button click increment by 2

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            if (ViewState["datacount"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["datacount"] = 0;
            }
            ViewState["datacount"] = ((int)ViewState["datacount"]) + 2;
            Label1.Text = DateTime.Today.AddDays((int)ViewState["datacount"]).ToString("dd");
        }
```

I hope this may helpful for you

**Note : viewstate data can maintain in same page only, can maintain in multiple pages**

Comment: Prasad -- This worked perfectly. To be honest I did not think about using viewstate. --Thanks!

Comment: its my pleasure dr

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are adding 2 days to TODAY's date every time.  What you want to do is add 2 to the date already stored there.  You would want to do something like this (warning: have not tried compiling this).

```
lblCurrentDate.Text = DateTime.Parse(lblCurrentDate.Text).AddDays(2).ToString("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

The parameter passed to `ToString()` formats the datetime.  You can modify that to get different formats.  If you want to  only store the days and not the month/year then you might need to do some more work.  Hope this helps.

Comment: have to test your code it will give you `System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: @Ansari I suppose it would if your string was not formatted properly.  [Here's an example](https://ideone.com/7MCOhf) that compiles and runs properly.